# Selecting between two transformers

Tags: transformer

I'm after a transformer providing a 24V output.
I have the option of choosing between two toroidal transformers with these secondary windings:

1. 2x12V 160VA
2. 2x24V 160VA

They are the same price. I can either wire option 1 in series to get the 24V or option 2 in parallel to get one 24V output. Is there any difference between these two given they have the same power rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend option 1: 2 x 12V, and connect these in series.

Reason: this forces the currents in each 12V winding to be identical (*).  The other option does not ensure **perfect** current sharing in the secondary windings, which can become particularly important if you want to extract maximum power.

(*) Assuming the load is connected **across** the series connection, and there is no part of the load connected to the join of the two windings.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, or even likely, that you will get the same results by wiring the 2 24V secondaries in parallel as you would by wiring the 2 12V secondaries in series. However, there is a problem associated with connecting two secondary windings in parallel. If the two windings do not have the same voltage when disconnected, there will be a "balancing" action, when they are connected in parallel. The voltages *must* become equal when they are in parallel, but the mechanism by which this will be accomplished is by having more current in one, and hence more I*R voltage drop, than in the other.

If you choose the 2x12 volt secondaries and connect them in series, you will have one less thing to worry about.